# Having a user resize columns in ngTable

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

The `ngTable` [web page](http://ng-table.com) mentions a plugin to resize columns (see point #12). But the example is still pending (it points to a TODO page) and there's no documentation. Any ideas if it's possible to resize columns in `ngTable`?